# Optimizing Pandas Function with Numba

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, numba

This program takes a Time Series in Matrix format, one of the Matrix's columns is Volume, the program then condenses and expands rows so that each row ultimately has the same volume whilst maintaining temporal order. This is done so that low volume events don't add heteroscedasticity to TS calculations. I've been trying to optimize a pandas function due to high memory usage and slowness, I've written the following and attempted to put it in to Numba but I'm not getting any performance boosts off the numba jit.
I was wondering how I can best optimize this function so that it works fast and doesn't melt my computer down due to lack of memory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@jit((float64[:], int64))
def create_new_df(df):
    ndf = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Volume)]
                .assign(Volume=1,
                        groups=lambda x: np.arange(len(x))//750
                       )
                .groupby('groups')
                .agg({'Timestamp':'first',
                      'Volume':'sum',
                      'C':'mean',
                      'D':'mean',
                      'E':'mean',
                      'F':'mean',
                      'G':'mean'}))
```

For len(x)//750 this (abridged for brevity):

```
Timestamp Volume C          D           E           F         G

23:32:03   1    57.05      57.05       57.05       57.05     57.05

23:32:04   0    57.05      57.05       57.05       57.05     57.05

...

23:32:55   0    57.05      57.05       57.05       57.05     57.05

23:32:56   2    57.04      57.04       57.04       57.04     57.04

23:32:57   0    57.04      57.04       57.04       57.04     57.04

23:32:58   0    57.04      57.04       57.04       57.04     57.04
```

Becomes this (also abridged for brevity):

```
Timestamp Volume    C           D           E           F       G

23:32:03  750   57.10   57.10   57.10   57.10   57.10

09:05:14  750   57.07   57.07   57.07   57.07   57.07

11:26:11  750   57.14   57.14   57.14   57.14   57.14

13:40:21  750   57.12   57.12   57.12   57.12   57.12

00:18:15  750   57.44   57.45   57.44   57.45   57.45
```

Comment: The error message is pretty informative, you cannot supply two types in your argument apparently. It would help if you added a small example dataset.

Comment: Fixed but still doesn't offer any measurable performance increase. I went on peopleperhour offered $50 for someone who could just put this in to good high preformance cython so I could be done with it all, guy on peopleperhour sends me back horrendous code, I've been trying to figure this out for weeks. I'm beyond frustrated. I just want to get something together that works reasonably well so I can move on from this all. I have a mate named Erfan from Bandar-e Anzali by the way.

Comment: Like I said, add an example dataframe and what your expected output is. Numba works well with numpy arrays, not very well with pandas dataframes.

Comment: I have it in pandas because I haven't been able to figure out how to properly code it in Numpy. I know that it would be far better in Numpy than pandas, the best option would be Cython/Numpy it's just I don't know how to program that, so this in pandas is the best I can do. I also added numerical examples like you requested

Comment: It's hard to say anything definite, given that the image you have provided just has black boxes. But it seems that you don't need the call to `df.index.repeat()`, which, I imagine, must be the culprit around memory issues. `Volume` can be assigned without `repeat`, `groups` and every aggregate after `groupby` can be computed differently by taking `B` into account.

Comment: For some reason copying off of libreoffice automatically tries to put a jpg in the post. So I just manually wrote out what the csv says.

Comment: Ah, now I get what you're trying to do. It's not a trivial task. I think the best way to solve it would be to iterate over the groups yourself. You will have to determine where each group ends, that's where `df['B'].expanding().sum()` along with `searchsorted(1000, 'right')` can help you. You need to effectively remove a group from the `df` on each iteration, and iterate over it till there are no groups left. You will also have to carefully take into account the fact that neighbor groups can start and end on the same row - you will have to effectively split the row then.

Comment: No, it sounds like it should be something that would be really easy and straight forward: expand and condense the input array so that the volume bar is equal for every row, unfortunately it is nightmare implementing.

Comment: @Erfan I made the edits you recommended, do you have any suggestions regarding the code?